# Sencha Touch XML List

Tags: javascript, xml, frameworks, sencha-touch

Hei i have a Question about XML Lists with Sencha Touch.

I load some XML in Sencha Touch and i would like to display them as a List:

Here's my Code:
Sencha:

```
Ext.setup({  
onReady: function() {   
Ext.regModel('navModel', {
  fields: [
       {name:'id'},
       {name:'title'}
       ]
});

var navi = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad:true,
    model: 'navModel',
    method: 'POST',
    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : 'navi.xml',
    reader: {
    type : 'xml',
root: 'menu',
record:'navigation'
 }
}  
});
   var something = new Ext.List({
        store: 'navi',
        title: 'asdfasdf',
        emptyText: 'No data',
        fulscreen: true,
        itemTpl: '{id} - {title}'
    });


       var rootPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
            fullscreen:true,
            items:[something]
        }); 

    }

});
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <menu>
    <navigation>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Hello</title>
    </navigation>
    <navigation>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Test</title>
    </navigation>
   </menu>
```

I can read the XML but it doesn't display it in the List.. what's wrong??

Thx for Answers

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the TabPanel to Container, that maybe help you!

Comment: could you please elaborate more the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the name of the store without the quote sign.

And for all who got problems with mapping...

you have to add this workaround on the end of sencha-touch.js:

```
Ext.override( Ext.data.XmlReader, {
    createAccessor: function() {
        var selectValue = function(key, root, defaultValue){
            if( key == '#' ){
                return root.tagName;
            }
            if( key.indexOf( '@' ) != -1 ){
                var property = key.split( '@' )[ 1 ];
                key = key.split( '@' )[ 0 ];
            }
            var val;
            if( key.length ){
                var node = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode(key, root);
                if( node && node.firstChild ){
                    node = node.firstChild;
                }
            }
            else{
                var node = root;
            }
            if(node){
                if( typeof( node.getAttribute ) != 'undefined' && typeof( property ) != 'undefined' ){
                    val = node.getAttribute( property );
                }
                else{
                    val = node.nodeValue;
                }
            }
            return Ext.isEmpty(val) ? defaultValue : val;
        };

        return function(key) {
            var fn;

            if (key == this.totalProperty) {
                fn = function(root, defaultValue) {
                    var value = selectValue(key, root, defaultValue);
                    return parseFloat(value);
                };
            }

            else if (key == this.successProperty) {
                fn = function(root, defaultValue) {
                    var value = selectValue(key, root, true);
                    return (value !== false && value !== 'false');
                };
            }

            else {
                fn = function(root, defaultValue) {
                    return selectValue(key, root, defaultValue);
                };
            }

            return fn;
        };
    }(),
});
```

so you can access the attribute of your xml with '@attributename'

and if you want to have access to the child attributes you write 'childname@attributename'

I hope i helped you.. searched some hours for this.. ;)